# async/await function return undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sequelize.js

Below is part of my function that must be performed asynchronously. why in a commented place it is undefined, since the function returns a value. And if my code is incorrect, can I see how it should look correctly?

```
    async function addAvailableFunds(
        recipientAvailableFunds,
        amountMoney,
        recipientId,
        transferCurrencyId,
      ) {
          const convertedAmountMoney = await currencyConversion(
            transferCurrencyId,
            recipientCurrencyId,
            amountMoney,
          );

          console.log(
            'convertedAmountMoney',
            convertedAmountMoney,
          ); // undefined


  async function currencyConversion(
    transferCurrencyId,
    recipientCurrencyId,
    amountMoney,
  ) {
    console.log('transferCurrencyId', transferCurrencyId);
    console.log('recipientCurrencyId', recipientCurrencyId);
    console.log('amountMoney', amountMoney);

    await Currency.findOne({
      where: {
        id: recipientCurrencyId,
      },
    }).then(async isRecipientCurrencyId => {
      if (isRecipientCurrencyId) {
        const mainCurrency = isRecipientCurrencyId.main_currency;
        const recipientCurrencyExchangeRate =
          isRecipientCurrencyId.currency_exchange_rate;

        console.log('mainCurrency', mainCurrency);
        console.log(
          'recipientCurrencyExchangeRate',
          recipientCurrencyExchangeRate,
        );

        await Currency.findOne({
          where: {
            id: transferCurrencyId,
          },
        }).then(isTransferCurrencyId => {
          if (isTransferCurrencyId) {
            const transferCurrencyExchangeRate =
              isTransferCurrencyId.currency_exchange_rate;

            console.log(
              'transferCurrencyExchangeRate',
              transferCurrencyExchangeRate,
            );

            if (mainCurrency) {

              const convertedAmountMoney =
                (amountMoney / transferCurrencyExchangeRate) *
                recipientCurrencyExchangeRate;
              console.log('convertedAmountMoney', convertedAmountMoney);
              return convertedAmountMoney; // return number
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

console.log returns a number so I do not know what's going on. console.log returns a number so I do not know what's going on.

Comment: Since you're using `await`, you should not use `then`.

Comment: Please edit your example code to just enough to illustrate the issue you are having. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the Promise `then` pattern with that of `async/await`.

These are two different and incompatible coding patterns. `await` returns a non-Promise value (only within the context of an `async` function), but `then` never returns anything other than another Promise.

Either use `async/await` or Promises, but not both in the same logic.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your `currencyConversion` you are mixing two approaches to handle functions that return promises.

You do:

`await Currency.findOne(...params..).then(...params..);`

Although you would like to do the following as you are using `async/await` syntax:

```
let isRecipientCurrencyId = await Currency.findOne(...params..);
...rest of the code..
```

[async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Answer (score 0):

`convertedAmountMoney` was undefined because nothing was returned in `currencyConversion`. You returned inside a `.then` inside some other promise, but `currencyConversion` itself returned nothing.

I've fixed your code below so as to go fully `async/await`, but there are three `else`s you'll have to handle yourself, because as of now your you didn't precised what to do then. I added three warnings for this.

```js
async function addAvailableFunds(
  recipientAvailableFunds,
  amountMoney,
  recipientId,
  transferCurrencyId,
) {
  const convertedAmountMoney = await currencyConversion(
    transferCurrencyId,
    recipientCurrencyId,
    amountMoney,
  );

  console.log(
    'convertedAmountMoney',
    convertedAmountMoney,
  ); // undefined
}


async function currencyConversion(
  transferCurrencyId,
  recipientCurrencyId,
  amountMoney,
) {
  console.log('transferCurrencyId', transferCurrencyId);
  console.log('recipientCurrencyId', recipientCurrencyId);
  console.log('amountMoney', amountMoney);

  const isRecipientCurrencyId = await Currency.findOne({
    where: {
      id: recipientCurrencyId,
    },
  })
  if (isRecipientCurrencyId) {
    const mainCurrency = isRecipientCurrencyId.main_currency;
    const recipientCurrencyExchangeRate =
      isRecipientCurrencyId.currency_exchange_rate;

    console.log('mainCurrency', mainCurrency);
    console.log(
      'recipientCurrencyExchangeRate',
      recipientCurrencyExchangeRate,
    );

    const isTransferCurrencyId = await Currency.findOne({
      where: {
        id: transferCurrencyId,
      },
    })

    if (isTransferCurrencyId) {
      const transferCurrencyExchangeRate =
        isTransferCurrencyId.currency_exchange_rate;

      console.log(
        'transferCurrencyExchangeRate',
        transferCurrencyExchangeRate,
      );

      if (mainCurrency) {
        const convertedAmountMoney =
          (amountMoney / transferCurrencyExchangeRate) *
          recipientCurrencyExchangeRate;
        console.log('convertedAmountMoney', convertedAmountMoney);
        return convertedAmountMoney; // return number
      }
      console.warn('Will return undefined');
    }
    console.warn('Will return undefined');
  }
  console.warn('Will return undefined');
}
```